# Verificar se os valores de uma array são todos iguais PHP?

Tags: php, array, arraylist

Gostaria de verificar se todos os valores da minha array são iguais e fiz de seguinte modo :

```
$minha_lista = array('a','a','a');

if(!empty($minha_lista)) {
    if(count(array_unique($minha_lista))===1){
             return true;
        } else { return false; }
    }
```

Infelizmente não consigo obter o resultado pretendido.

Existe uma outra forma de proceder ?

Comment: Mas, pelo visto se código está certo, o que tem de errado ou que ele não faz?

Comment: o seu código está correto, não precisa de nada! só se tiver alguma coisa que não está relatando na sua pergunta ... !!!

Comment: @andré-pka Existe algum outro problema que está ocorrendo? Pois como o amigo acima disse... Seu código está correto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem algumas formas de fazer essa verificação, por exemplo:

```
if(count(array_unique($minha_lista))){
    //...
}
```

ou mesmo:

```
if($minha_lista === array_fill(0,count($minha_lista),$minha_lista[0])){
    //...
}
```

Aqui as documentações das funções: 
[array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php), 
[array_fill](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php)

Answer (score 5):

Você pode fazer com um loop, assim:

```
$arr = ['aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa'];
$status = true;

foreach($arr as $value) {
    if($arr[0] != $value) {
         $status = false;
         break;
    }
}
```

A variável `$status` começa como `true` e se durante o `loop` com o `array` for encontrado algum valor diferente, ele muda pra `false`

Answer (score 3):

O seu código está correto. Deixei ele mais "explícito", dê uma olhada:

```
$check_array = ('a', 'a', 'a');

$result_array = array_unique($check_array);

if (count($result_array) == 1)
   echo "Valores iguais...";
else
   echo "Valores diferentes...";
```